# Show that the sum of a set of matrices isn't direct, and that the sum is the whole vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

Let $U$ be upper triangular matrices in $M_2$ and $L$ lower triangular matrices in $M_2$. Show that their sum isn't direct, and that their sum is the whole vector space.

I have the following definitions:

> If $L\cap M=\{0\}$, then we say that that is the direct sum. Notation: $L\oplus M$.
>
> If $L\oplus M=V$, we say that $M$ is a direct complement for $L$ and vice versa.

I know that an upper triangular matrix can be written as $\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\0 & d\end{pmatrix}$ and lower triangular as $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\c & 0\end{pmatrix}$. If I add them up, I get $\begin{pmatrix} a &b \\c & d\end{pmatrix}$.
But how do I prove their sum is the whole space $M_2$? And what about direct sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

In $M_2(\mathbb{K})$, [Lower triangular matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Description) have the form:
$$
\begin {pmatrix}
m&0\\
n&q
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so the intersection of $L$ and $M$ is the set of all diagonal matrices (and this answer to your first question).

For the second question, show that any matrix of the form
$$
\begin {pmatrix}
x&y\\
z&t
\end{pmatrix}
$$
can be expressed as a sum:
$$
\begin {pmatrix}
x&y\\
z&t
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin {pmatrix}
0&0\\
z&0
\end{pmatrix}+
\begin {pmatrix}
x&y\\
0&t
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where the two matrices are elements of $L$ and $M$.

Comment: Why do I have to show that any matrix in $M_2$ can be expressed as a linear combination of elements in $L$ and $U$?

Comment: Sorry. My answer was not clear. I've edit and I hope that now it's better.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer above is incomplete, and I'd like to complete it. In order for $M_2(\mathbb{K})$ to not be equal to the direct sum, this is, for $M_2(\mathbb{K})$ to differ from $U \bigoplus L$ we need to know the definition of direct sum which says:

> each $x$ in $F_1 + ... + F_n$ is written in an unique way as the sum $x = x_1 + ... + x_n $

which is equivalent to say:

> for each $j = 1, ..., k$ we have $F_j \bigcap (F_1 + ... + F_{j-1} + F_{j+1}+...+ F_n) = \{0\}$

and it's evident that $M_2(\mathbb{K})$ isn't written as a superior and inferior triangular matrices in an unique way. That's why, we say that the direct sum is different from $M_2$.

*Source: Alégra Linear, Elon Lages (a brazilian mathematician).*